# L100 John deere engine 17hp replace with 21hp?

Tags: engine, replacements

Can a L100 John Deere 17hp engine be replaced with a John Deere 21hp engine?

Comment: Anything is possible. Do you have specific concerns about doing this? You'll need to narrow down the question more for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The JD 17hp engine will either be manufactured by Briggs & Stratton or Keohler. Depending on which 21hp engine you are looking at will let us know if it can be used in its place. The 17hp engine has a 4 bolt mounting plate on the bottom which is very common. I'd bet the 21hp engine you're looking at is setup the same. I'd also suspect the 21hp is a v-twin. What it actually is will differentiate whether it will bolt up or not, but more than likely it will. There would possibly be some wiring/exhaust things you'd need to sort.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 looks like the L100 [has a Briggs](http://www.tractordata.com/lawn-tractors/000/0/6/64-john-deere-l100-engine.html), and I'm guessing it's probably the [Intek 31F707-0112](http://www.smallenginewarehouse.com/Repower-Old-Equipment/John-Deere-L100-Category/).

Comment: Yes the L100 uses the Briggs engine.